# Disable unnecessary ComboBox backend call

Tags: java, vaadin, vaadin7

I can see that when I click on the ComboBox it is sending a request to the backend. It is true even if imediate and validation are set as false. Is it possible to disable this behaviour?

It is unexpected and unnecessary, since ComboBox store a list of static values and there is no need to reload this on each click. Could you please advise.

Details:

```
final ComboBox hoursToExpire = new ComboBox("Hours until expires:", hours);
        hoursToExpire.setTextInputAllowed(false);
        hoursToExpire.setNullSelectionAllowed(false);
        hoursToExpire.setValue(1);
```

With this configuration, a backend call is made when:

- ComboBox clicked,
- select a value

When I specify

```
hoursToExpire.setImmediate(false)
```

Then a, a backend call is made when:

- ComboBox clicked

This is unnecessary and I am trying to disable this.

Comment: For example value change listeners make ComboBox immediate nowdays. Try to call setImmediate(false) later..

Comment: setImmediate is helping with disabling backend call when value selected, but there is still a backend call when ComboBox clicked. Please see Details section.

Comment: Clicking the combobox opens its dropdown?

Comment: That's how ComboBox works. If you have only a few items on the dropdown, you could consider using a NativeSelect.

Comment: Native select work as expected, however it is not styled as good as ComboBox. Is there any way to use hybrid of Native simplicity and ComboBox elegancy? Please see that in simple cases ComboBox wouldn't have get any lazy loaded data from backend

Comment: I understand what you mean but as far as I know it's not possible. If you want you could create a ticket about at https://dev.vaadin.com/.